# windows10: task scheduler: basic task: how to run a task every one hour

Tags: windows-10

Windows 10:

How to run a task every one hour using task scheduler.

I tried and see no option for hour. I have to create a basic task.

Can anyone guide me in this regard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In the Task Scheduler Library, right click on the task and select Properties
2. Select the Triggers tab
3. Select the Trigger and click Edit
4. Begin the task: On a schedule
5. Select One time and define the start time
6. In Advance Settings:
   [image]

Comment: So this start everyday and that task will run per every hour indefinitely.

arent we creating a new indefinite task everyday

Comment: No, we are starting the task only once by selecting 'One Time' on step 5, from then on, we will run this task every hour and this will go on indefinitely.

Comment: also if the computer is powered off inbetween, hope it will still work

Answer (score 0):

Better to set it to run "Daily" and "Recur every 1 days".

Then in advanced settings, set it to "repeat task every 1 hour" "for a duration of 1 day".